# Error al fusionar pagina HTML

Tags: python, django

Tengo el siguiente error cuando voy a renderizar y fusionar el HTML blog(es raro porque cuando renderize otro HTML no tuve ningún problema):
[image: Página donde debería mostrarse el blog y muestra un error.]

Dejo los códigos de los 4 archivos que use.

Archivo views.py (donde Visual Studio Code este error en la línea 7: Class 'Post' has no 'objects' member pylint(no-member) [7, 13]

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.

def blog(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, "blog/blog.html", {'posts':posts})
```

blog.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in posts %}  
    <section class="page-section cta">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
            <div class="cta-innerv text-center rounded">
              <h2 class="section-heading mb-5">
                <span class="section-heading-upper">{{post.published}}</span>
                <span class="section-heading-lower">{{post.title}}</span>
              </h2>
              <p class="mb-0">
                <img class="mx-auto d-flex rounded img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="">
              </p>
              <p class="mb-0 mbt">{{post.content}}</p>
              <p class="mb-0 mbt">
                <span class="section-heading-under">Publicado por <em><b>{{post.author}}</b></em> en <em>
                <a href="#" class="link">General</a>, <a href="#" class="link">Ofertas</a></em></span>
              </p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | La Caffettiera</title>

    {% load static %}

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{% static 'core/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fuentes -->
    <link href="{% static 'core/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Estilos -->
    <link href="{% static 'core/css/business-casual.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <h1 class="site-heading text-center text-white d-none d-lg-block">
      <span class="site-heading-upper text-primary mb-3">L'autentico caffè d'italia</span>
      <span class="site-heading-lower">La Caffettiera</span>
    </h1>

    <!-- Navegación -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark py-lg-4" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase text-expanded font-weight-bold d-lg-none" href="{% url 'home' %}">La Caffettiera</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item px-lg-4 {% if request.path == '/' %}active{% endif %}">
              <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'home' %}">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-lg-4 {% if request.path == '/about/' %}active{% endif %}">
              <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'about' %}">Historia</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-lg-4 {% if request.path == '/services/' %}active{% endif %}">
              <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'services' %}">Servicios</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-lg-4 {% if request.path == '/store/' %}active{% endif %}">
              <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'store' %}">Visítanos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-lg-4 {% if request.path == '/contact/' %}active{% endif %}">
              <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contacto</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-lg-4 {% if request.path == '/blog/' %}active{% endif %}">
              <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Contenido -->
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    <!-- Pié de página -->
    <footer class="footer text-faded text-center py-5">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0">
            <a href="#" class="link">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="link">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="link">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class="m-0 mbt">
            <a href="sample.html" class="link">Política de privacidad</a> ·
            <a href="sample.html" class="link">Aviso legal</a> ·
            <a href="sample.html" class="link">Cookies</a>
        </p>
        <p class="m-0 mbt1">&copy; La Caffettiera 2018</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="{% static 'core/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blog, name="blog"),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Nombre")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de edición")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "categoría"
        verbose_name_plural = "categorías"
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Título")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Contenido")
    published = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Fecha de publicación", default=now)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Imagen", upload_to="blog", null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Autor", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Categorías")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de actualización")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "entrada"
        verbose_name_plural = "entradas"
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Actualizo:

Me he dado cuenta que el problema está en la imagen que subo para cada entrada del blog ya que si dejamos sin imagen una entrada tendrá este error. Pero no entiendo porque si el código tiene null y blank igual a True para poder dejar la entrada sin imagen.

Comment: Saludos José, ¿podrías colocar todo el código que tienes para poder reproducir tu escenario, por favor?

Comment: @fredyfx espero te sirvan de ayuda

Comment: ¿y el modelo? Me gustaría saber qué hay en `Post.objects.all()` y la definición de `Post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba agregar en tu template de blog.html una condicional para que verifique primero si hay una imagen:

```
{% if post.image %}
<p class="mb-0">
<img class="mx-auto d-flex rounded img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="">
</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Tu aporte resuelve el problema. Gracias!